# regarding SSL_do_handshake bloocking call

Tags: c, openssl, dtls

I am calling SSL_do_handshake with underlying BIO as blocking, means it will wait till handshake is done or error occured.
Is there any way so that i can cancel this waiting call (waiting on SSL_do_handshake) from some other thread.
i used SSL_clear,SSL_shutdown,SSL_free methods but thread is still waiting on SSL_do_handshake function call.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This is not nice way, but it should work:

Close the underlying TCP socket by using `close()`.

Any blocking IO with the socket will fail, and `SSL_do_handshake()` returns error.

But be carefully when closing sockets from other thread, because file descriptor numbers can be reused.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But i can not close socket FD as i am getting this FD from some other program for temporary use for connection. Can  another method make ssl/BIO non blocking from other thread? is it possible and right way?

Comment: Use `BIO_get_fd()` to get the underlying file descriptor, then use `ioctl` with `FIONBIO` to change the blocking mode. I think you will also need to create a `BIO` pair to handle the callback.

Comment: Changing Blocking mode does not work. i was trying for other option like SSL_connect (client) and SSL_accept(server) for the replacement of SSL_do_handshake. But still i am not able to getting timeout base call for client and server side coding. Can you explain me with example for setting BIO related coding for timeout and callback, if you have any idea.

Comment: i made the following changes and it seems working(at least as of now):  1). i am using SSL_connect and SSL_accept(i think SSL_do_handshakeshould also work) and socket i am using in non-blocking mode. 2) I am checking of the return status of SSL_connect/accept , if SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ/WRITE is coming i am calling SSL_connect/accept again. 3) for wait/timeout i am calling select().